# Highstocks fixed x-axis with ordinal true

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using **Highstock.js** to build a stock ticker that spans three days.  I am using a line to graph the S & P 500 vs time, and I have a data point for every minute the market is open.  I also have a feed sending a new data point every minute.  When the page loads the previous two days of data is loaded into the chart, plus all the data available so far today.  Then I update with new data each minute.

All data is displayed correctly, but I am trying to split the x-axis into thirds (with no gaps). Each third would correspond to each day.  This means the last third would only be partially filled while the current day's data is coming in.  The line graph would be moving toward the edge of the chart.

The issue I am running into is that the line always fills the entire chart.

I have tried setting the `xAxis.max`, but this doesn't work unless I set `xAxis.ordinal = false`.  but that leaves gaps for nights, weekends, holidays, etc...

I have also tried sorting and ignoring the x value, but it has become a headache to account for weekends and holidays.  Plus I don't know how to get the axis labels back to the correct time.

**Basically I'm asking, Is it possible to create a chart that is only partially filled, without** `ordinal = false`

Comment: Yes you can add null values in the serie.

Comment: Do you mean that I should add as many null values as I need space?  e.g. the series might look like ```[[1, 5], [2, 11], [3, null], [4, null], [5, null]]```